# How to create a Parallax Fixed Header with react-spring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parallax, react-spring

I want to create a Parallax Fixed Header effect (fixed header scrolling body), like the one used in these pages.

http://somethingsplendid.com/

http://jsfiddle.net/KsdeX/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=KsdeX

How can I achieve it using `react-spring` Parallax? For the header to be fixed at the top and everything else scrolling until it covers the header then the scrolling resumes normally. Cannot figure out how to do it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If its still relevant for you or somebody.
Just use `position:sticky; top: 0;` on the Header.
And be sure that the parent tag is a the whole other body of where you want that header to be sticked.